# Invalid char between encapsulated token and delimiter

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8, mlcp

While trying to load csv files using MLCP, the insertion of records get skipped due to following error:

```
invalid char between encapsulated token and delimiter
```

I found out that it’s due to \” in the csv file, which needs to be replaced with \’. Is there any option in MLCP to automate this using ‘**find and replace**’?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using -split_input?  See

https://github.com/marklogic/marklogic-contentpump/issues/57

You can try it without that option.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very difficult to answer with little to no context and has nothing to do with MLCP or MarkLogic per se. Having some knowledge of how your CSV files are built, I can tell you that you want to change the \" to "". That can be done from the command line using standard Linux commands that a quick Google search can provide.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend prepping the file with tools other than **MLCP**. You could perform a find and replace with **sed** in the following way in bash:

```
sed -i -e 's/\"/\'/g' file-to-ingest.csv
```